# Visual Studio 2012: C++ compiler ignoring user-specified include directories

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, mfc

I have the common error `fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'afxres.h': No such file or directory`. Search engines show up lots of hits for this, but none of the suggested solutions work for me.

Normally this would appear to be a problem with the paths. So, I ensured the relevant libraries were installed, and located the file. Using the absolute path as the #include works fine:

`#include "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\atlmfc\include\afxres.h"`

But, if I add the directory (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\atlmfc\include) to the project settings (or to Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.User property sheet), and try this line:

`#include "afxres.h"`

I get the error C1083 again. Yet Visual Studio clearly can find the file - if I right-click on the filename and select "Open Document 'afxres.h'" then it opens it immediately!

Why would Visual Studio be ignoring the #include path that I specified? Other #include paths I've included in a similar way work perfectly.

[image: Directory is explicitly included in the build settings]

Comment: As far as I know afxres.h should be application specific; it is not a standard library include, it is generated for using resources in your project

Comment: Can't test as I'm not in Windows these days, but try **Tools>Options>Directories**

Comment: @hll `afxres.h` is included with MFC.

Comment: @JohnDibling: the old tools>options>directories way doesn't work any more - you configure the directories via the project settings or the property manager (which is what I did).

Comment: I remember having a similar issue on Win7 and this VStudio version (if this is for Win8 ignore it). Haven't you looked at the VC++ Directories->Include Directories field, is the path of what you expect already included?

Comment: Did your configuration string really have the parentheses around it? If so remove them.

Comment: @notNullGothik: yes, that is what I meant when I said I'd added it to the project settings.

Comment: @MarkRansom: no, I just added the plain directory.

Comment: Tried that, made no difference. (As I understand it, it should only affect the order rather than whether it finds it or not. Tried it anyway.)

Comment: Try this: Project -> Properties -> C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories, put the path to your file there

Comment: I've attached a picture showing how I've added the path, since people keep offering the obvious suggestions.

Comment: The path you are adding contains spaces. Have you tried to use double quotes '"' around it?

Comment: @Tomek: good suggestion! Doesn't make any difference though. :)

Comment: How did you get `VC++ Directories` to show up in `Common Properties`? I need to select a specific Project and use `Configuration Properties` to see it.

Comment: @MarkRansom: No idea. It's always been there for me (in recent versions of VC++), and that's how I configure system-wide libraries (via the Ms.Win32.Cpp sheet), usually.

Comment: You might try making the change to a specific project and see if it works there.

Comment: Yeah, tried that, no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but I did have Visual C++ 2010 Express on here previously, from which it seems to have imported some settings

That was the essential comment.  Express doesn't support ATL and MFC.  What's still missing is that you only got this problem on projects that you started on VS2010 previously.

Do note that adding the path like you did in the project property sheet was not necessary.  Visible in the screen-shot, it is already covered by the `$(VCInstallDir)atlmfc\include` entry in the inherited properties.  So the conclusion to draw is that the $(VCInstallDir) macro value is wrong.

Short from an install mishap or a whacked registry, this can happen when you converted a project that you previously started in VS2010.  Switch back from the Property Manager to the Solution Explorer window, right-click your project, Properties, General page.  Change the "Platform Toolset" setting from v100 to v110.  You'll now use the VS2012 include directories instead of the VS2010 Express ones.

Beware that changes to the Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.User project property sheet will affect *all* your projects, you'll want to reset it back.

Comment: Hans, I think you are overstating things somewhat. Every other project builds and links just fine. All I have changed in that property sheet is to add 2 directories which I need to be found globally. Since it wasn't finding the MFC header, this seemed like a useful place to put it, since it should be globally accessible.

Comment: And I can confirm that taking out the additional include directories - which is all that I ever changed, incidentally - does not resolve the problem.

Comment: ...nor does replacing my file with your version. This is a fresh installation of VS2012 (ie. installed 2 days ago) but I did have Visual C++ 2010 Express on here previously, from which it seems to have imported some settings.

Comment: Let's keep our eye on the ball.  Adding the atlmfc/include directory was completely unnecessary, it already is added.  It is visible in your screenshot, the $(VCInstallDir)atlmfc/include setting takes care of it.  What I can't see are the *project* settings for the include directories.  The compiler error strongly suggests that it is wrong.  If this is the Express edition then you need to mention that too.

Comment: Actually, I think you have helped me find the problem, indirectly. As you say, the $(VCInstallDir)atlmfc/include setting *should* take care of it, but it doesn't. And I've just found that $(VCInstallDir) is wrong - it points at the old 2010 Express directory rather than my new 2012 directory. This in turn seems to be because Visual Studio has all the "Platform Toolset" for these projects set to 2010 - and my copy of 2010 has no MFC, obviously.

Comment: Hi Hans, can you clarify what is meant by "does not support"? What makes ATL and MFC different from other libraries, that Express cannot handle them?

Comment: @ILikeFood: I would guess that express merely does not ship with the ATL and MFC headers.

Comment: I'm really sad, because I'm having this exact same issue as the OP, except it's one of our internal headers, and so there's no `$(VCInstallDir)` or similar in the path :<

Answer (score 1):

First, ensure that MFC is enabled in project properties > Configuration Properties > General

use of mfc must be set to static or dynamic library.

secondly, to ensure that cl.exe is using all of the include directories that you specify, you need to go to project properties > c/c++ > general and change suppress startup banner to no /nologo-

this will give you the full cl command for each source file, showing exactly what visual studio is attempting to do with the code and configuration options that you give to it.

eg. `cl /c /ZI /nologo- /W3 /WX- /Od /Oy- /D WIN32 /D _DEBUG /D _CONSOLE /D _UNICODE /D UNICODE /Gm /EHsc /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Yc"StdAfx.h" /Fp"Debug\test.pch" /Fo"Debug\\" /Fd"Debug\vc100.pdb" /Gd /TP /showIncludes /analyze- /errorReport:prompt stdafx.cpp`

If it is using your extra include folders, you should see a lot of extra `-I` switches in the command line.